# How do I list 100 files in a directory, in batches?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a directory with 1000 files. I would like to break the files into groups of 100,
and run 10 batch commands, each command taking one batch.

So, if the files are named
     ABC.1, ABC.2,ABC.3 ..... ABC.1000

I would like to run one command on ABC.1 -> ABC.99, then another command 
on ABC.100 -> ABC.199, etc.

So, ideally, I would filter the dir command to give me 100 files starting from a specified file.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

cd /d C:\temp\abc
for /f "tokens=2 delims=." %%a in ('dir /b /a-d ABC*') do (
   if %%a GTR 0 if %%a LEQ 99 echo do something with ABC.%%a
   if %%a GTR 99 if %%a LEQ 199 echo do something else with ABC.%%a
   if %%a GTR 199 if %%a LEQ 299 echo do another thing with ABC.%%a
)
```

Just add in all of the additional cases and change the echoing to actually do something. Change the cd /d to the folder your files are in.